# Setting breakpoints in Eclipse for Additional Source .zip files

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am a relatively inexperienced Java programmer (lots of experience in other languages) working on an issue in a large complicated program which I did not write. The issue is occurring in using the Apace axis library.  I downloaded the zip for it and added it as an external archive in my run/debug configuration. I can successfully step into the code but setting a break point does not work.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated; please make them as detailed as possible
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That source is for reference purposes only (so you can see the inner code).

In order to be able to add breakpoints, you should be recompiling the library, not just using the downloaded classes.